# Undefined reference error in jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

```
function callback(){
if(A.B.C)
{
some task;
}
}
```

I have to test the callback function. But the problem is that A.B is undefined. Only A is defined. How do I create A.B.C in my jasmine unit test? I'm getting an undefined reference error right now because B is undefined. B has many properties, C being one of them. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the code you've provided, `A` is undefined. You need to construct a [proper test case](http://sscce.org/) for us to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @Quentin in this test case, before the js file of this typescript test file gets loaded, there are other js files which get loaded and because of this A gets assigned. But the property B of A doesn't get assigned. So I wanted to mock it.

Comment: @user2597100 correct me if I'm wrong, but in your current `callback()` function, the only way `A` can get defined within the scope of this function is if `A` was defined on the global scope. Is this the case?

Comment: @NickZuber yup, A is defined on the global scope.

Comment: @user2597100 Do you think it could have something to do with referencing a global element in Jasmine? I don't know much about Jasmine itself so I could be pretty off... maybe try creating another global object and attempting to reference it in that `callback()` and see if you get the same undefined error.